# Does anybody know of a program like ScoreLoop or OpenFeint for blackberry phones?

Tags: blackberry, openfeint

I'm specifically trying to create a global high score list and something like this seems the easiest route. Does anybody know of a service or program for blackberry phones? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Scoreloop 1.0 in NDK 2.0 release? 
You have it for BlackBerry now. 
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/beta/?CPID=TWDToolDL&Date=112311

Comment: Thats just for blackberry tablet, I only program for phones :(

Answer (score 2):

Research In Motion (Blackberry) is working very closely with Scoreloop SDK. 
The acquisition of Scoreloop will be part of both BlackBerry 10 and BlackBerry PlayBook's stories for SDK product offerings, with social features of Scoreloop's SDK integrating with BBM Social Platform.

You may find sample Scoreloop integration codes here: https://github.com/blackberry/Scoreloop-Samples/tree/BB10.0.09/ScoreloopIntegrationSample

Requirement: BlackBerry 10 Native SDK and Simulator

Quick Start Guide: https://slbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/BB10_SL_Easy_start.pdf